# iPad Split Screen causes Drawer to be dark

Tags: ios, ipad, mmdrawercontroller, split-screen

I'm using an MMDrawerController to have a right-side drawer on my app. This works very well normally, but something gets weird when displayed in Split Screen on an iPad.

Here is a picture of the app with the right-side drawer open. You can see the Recents, Easy Modes, etc. It looks like a normal table.

[image]

However, if I drag open the split screen and then try to open the drawer, the drawer is very dark.

[image]

I'm still able to tap on the items in the drawer so whatever is causing the darkness isn't preventing taps.

Has anyone experienced this and found a solution for it?

Answer (score 0):

I imagine that it's the shadow not understanding what is happening with the split view, responding to the method viewWillTransition(to size: CGSize, with coordinator: UIViewControllerTransitionCoordinator) should help!